# How to calculate slearn.roc_auc_score using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, roc

I want to calculate and print `roc_auc_score` to evaluate the performance of my model (random forest), I am doing NLP, so my data in `y_test` and `y_pred` are basically list of words, I vectorise them with the function `pipe_vect.transform` but when I launch the training I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case."
```

I think the error appear because `y_test` and `y_pred` havn't the same dimension.

My code :

```
x_test_vect = pipe_vect.transform(x_test)
y_pred = model.predict_proba(x_test_vect)  
auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('Performance model :', auc_score)
```

Comment: your y_pred contain probabiltiy... and not class label

Comment: Please read closely the error message, which says that only one class is present in your true labels, and not tha tthere is a dimension mismatch